# Klaro consent manager in Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2.4.2

I tried to integrate [Klaro consent](https://github.com/kiprotect/klaro) in Magento 2.4.2 using two phtml-files that are loaded in the right order. In a test html-file the cookie consent is shown properly.

Both js-files are loaded in Magento and output a console.log.
But the Cookie consent is not shown at all. All caches (Magento and browser) are cleared – the console does not show any js-error. Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to find a solution:

1. I created a phtml-file with the config-script and integrated it in defaul.xml with

```
<referenceContainer name="whateveryouwant">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="klaro.config" template="Magento_Theme::html/klaro-config.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

2. In the modules requirejs-config.js I added the klaro.js

```
...
"map": {
     "*": {
          "klaro": "sources/klaro/klaro",
     }
},
...
```

3. Finally I started Klaro in my main.js with

```
require(['klaro'],function(klaro) {
   window.klaro = klaro; 
});
```

Final note: The CSS can be added default.xml. Also it is recommended to create a module.